# Cheerio Web Scraping - Editing & Styling the HTML

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm doing a web scraping exercise with Node and Cheerio, and I can successfully scrape the target website and return its HTML to my scrape page - using the following code:

```
app.get("/scrape", function(req, res, body) {

request("http://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/copa-do-mundo/classificacao.html", function(error, response, body) {

var $ = cheerio.load(body);

res.send($("div#widget-classificacao").html());

});
```

});

However, I'm having a hard time trying to edit and style the HTML I'm scraping. I wanna apply CSS and some Javascript to it on my page, but cannot find a way to target it correctly. How should I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that `res.send` only sends the response once, so if the `each` function is being executed multiple times for multiple elements, only the first one will be sent. Could this be the source of the error?

Comment: The each function is dispensable, I changed the code to

         request("http://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/copa-do-mundo/classificacao.html", function(error, response, body) {

  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  res.send($("div#widget-classificacao").html());


  });

And it still works the same way. I am not getting an error, I just want to be able to access and target the HTML I'm scraping so I can edit it.